# markdown to html using a specified css

Tags: python, css, vim, markdown

First, let me say - I love markdown. Truly love it. It's simple, it's elegant, it's sexy, it's everything I wish for in a markup language. If I could, I'd propose to it :)

So far I've been using it in a very nice and simple way, Vim + [python-markdown](http://www.freewisdom.org/projects/python-markdown/) = fast preview in my browser of choice.

But, it has one drawback ... the css sheet is hardcoded somewhere inside the plugin, and I can't change it. *Note: I know zero python, or something very close to it.*

**Is there a markdown to -various formats- plugin that lets you specify a css page to use, so that I could have several and create several versions of the same document using the one I wish at that time?**

It would go something like

```
markdown  my-document-in.markdown  css-sheet.css  cool-looking-document.html
```

Comment: +1 for loving markdown. me too.

Comment: @thephpdeveloper - No, seriously, it's one really beautiful thing. Simple yet so useful. If it had math support (for equations) I'd probably propose to it.

Comment: @Jonas - Looking at it now; I don't see anything in the docs regarding entering a chosen css sheet. Could you provide a hint or two?

Comment: @applicative - Why did you delete the answer? I checked out pandoc, and indeed, it is a wonderful project.

Comment: I'll add this as a comment rather than an answer because you'll probably hate me for suggesting it! The cross-platform editor "Sublime Text 2" has this capability via a plugin called "Markdown Preview". The CSS is in the plugins folder and is easily edited. Interestingly, ST2 is written in Python.

Answer (score 7):

Using https://github.com/trentm/python-markdown2/ (specifically https://raw.github.com/trentm/python-markdown2/master/lib/markdown2.py), I wrote a small script which when called as `generator.py input.markdown styles.css pretty.html` (assuming you saved it as generator.py) uses the python-markdown2 library to convert the markdown to HTML, embeds the css file in the top and writes it to pretty.html.

```
import markdown2
import os, sys


output = """<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
"""

cssin = open(sys.argv[2])
output += cssin.read()

output += """
    </style>
</head>

<body>
"""
mkin = open(sys.argv[1])
output += markdown2.markdown(mkin.read())

output += """</body>

</html>
"""

outfile = open(sys.argv[3])
outfile.write(output)
outfile.close()`
```

Copy the linked file from github and the code above into a folder together and it should run fine. I've tested it locally and it works. Hope it can help you too.

Comment: Note that since strings are immutable in python, using `+=` is a horrible thing to do, performance-wise. Since you're opening outfile anyway, better just write each piece separately.